# ScalaFX and FXML example doesnt seem to work

Tags: scala, scalafx

I am following this example [here](https://github.com/scalafx/ProScalaFX/blob/master/src/proscalafx/ch10/fxml/FXMLAdoptionForm.scala)

```
object DataEditor extends JFXApp {
  val resource = getClass.getResource("MainWindowView.FXML")
  if(resource == null){
    throw new IOException("Cannot load Resource")
  }
  val root:jfxs.Parent = jfxf.FXMLLoader.load(resource)

  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    title = "Data Editor"
    scene = new Scene(root)
  }
}
```

but for some reason `new Scene(root)` doesn't work as a constructor.

Root is meant to be javafx.scene and stage.scene is scalafx.scene.Scene so making root javafx.Parent doesn't work.

Have there been any changes to scalafx since these examples have been made??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was because I stuck stuff in the middle of SFXML and normal scalaFX

First thing I found was `import scalafx.Includes._` which is the one line I managed to ignore on the examples is a "magic line" that fixes all the weirdness between javaFX and scalaFX. This fixes the `No constructor` errors for `scene = new Scene(root)`

I had an @sfxml annotation on my controller class but wasn't loading it using SFXML's FXMLView which resulted in javafx failing to find a no args constructor.

And finally FXMLView requires a Dependency resolver (I.e. Subcut) but they also have a `NoDependencyResolver` object to save the bacon of us mortals who don't even need one yet `FXMLView(resource, NoDependencyResolver)`.